# Do I need a resistor to control a servo with a PWM signal?

Tags: pwm, resistor, pcb-design

I working with Arduino Nano Every that has several analog PWM pins. I want to use one to control a small servo.

Do I need to put a resistor between PWM pin and the servo signal?

Comment: It depends. In my case I had to add 1k resistor. https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/88609/long-servos-cable-causes-arduino-to-restart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't.

Resistors are used to limit and control current (amongst other things) and you don't need to do that when sending a signal from one digital device to another.